# Is this sentence confusing?

Tags: grammar

In Maureen Orth's "Vulgar Favours" she writes about serial killer Andrew Cunanan:

> He didn't really care whether they actually believed him or not, as
>   long as they went along with the conceit. And while many found this
>   charade harmless fun, psychologist Elizabeth Oglesby, who came to know
>   Andrew well, as **her** next-door neighbour and housesitter, didn't think
>   it was funny at all

I'm wondering about that last sentence. Would it have been better to write this?

> as **his** next-door neighbour and housesitter

The original sounds wrong, to my ears anyway.

Comment: The "He" as the first word refers to Andrew Cunanan. The "her" refers to Elizabeth Oglesby, who is presumably female. Andrew was her next-door neighbour and house-sitter. Why do you think it should be "his"? Presumably she wasn't his house-sitter: he was hers.

Comment: I know what she meant, but on first reading I have to admit was confused and thought it was an error. I didn't think it sounded right.

Comment: It's poorly written -- "run-on" from several standpoints.

Answer (score 1):

This is a mild example of what Steven Pinker calls a “garden path”
sentence: one that sets up a certain expectation and then leads the
reader in another direction.

We expect *as (someone’s) next-door neighbour and housesitter* to refer
to Elizabeth, and thus the pronoun to be *his*. But that clause actually
refers to *Andrew*.

Comment: The default referent here is the closest available noun group, 'Andrew'. In contrast, in "... Elizabeth Oglesby, who,  as his next-door neighbour and housesitter, came to know Andrew well", 'Elizabeth Oglesby' is the default referent for 'his next-door neighbour ...'.

Comment: Yes, that re-writing sounds much better, to my ears anyway. Thank you!